# How to solve () = 2(/2) +1 with Substitution Method

Tags: recursion, time-complexity, big-o, substitution

Here I got a recursive function and I want to  solve that ( finding the time complexity ) with **Substitution Method** *(mathematical induction)  .*

```
() = 2(/2) +1
```

In the question mentioned that our guess should be **Ω(log n)** . Actually I used  mathematical induction to prove that the **T(n) = O(n)** then because that **n = Ω(log n)** so the **T(n) is too** .but I was not successful to prove it correctly .

I have seen all the answers for this function that asked before but they were not solved with Substitution Method .  could you help me to prove that in this way .

Answer (score 0):

Your strategy is correct. We prove by induction that `T(n) = Theta(n)`.

We assume w.l.o.g. the initial condition `T(n) = 1`.

Induction hypothesis: `T(n) = 2n - 1`.

Base case: `T(1) = 1 = 2 * 1 - 1`.

Inductive case:

```
T(n) = 2T(n/2) + 1
     = 2 (2n/2 - 1) + 1 (inductive hypothesis)
     = 2n - 1 (QED)
```

Hence `T(n) = Theta(n)`, and from there it follows e.g. that `T(n) = Omega(log n)` etc.